# I cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2010

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on Win 7 32bit. It installed correctly and made a database. I opened Visual Studio 2010 and wrote a code that it connects to SQL Server.

```
cn = new SqlConnection();
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=XXX_amlak; User ID=sa; password=XXX";
cn.Open();
```

but I get this error.

> *SQLException was unhandled*
>   *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
>   connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to 
>   allow remote connections.(provider:Named Pipes Provider,error:40-could not open
>   a connection to SQL Server)*

Visual Studio has installed SQL Server Express automatically.

Comment: I'm confused... are you trying to connect to a Sql Server 2008 R2 instance, or to the SQL Express instance installed by Visual Studio?

Comment: Most probably you have installed SQl 2008R2 express. You will have to change the connection string such that Data Source=(local\SQLEXPRESS)

Comment: I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2. To SQL Management Studio.